# It's not possible customize timeout values

Tags: openstack, cloudify

I'm using Cloudify 2.7 with OpenStack Icehouse.

I have tried to insert the section "installer" into the cloud driver (computeTemplate, as suggested by the [official guide](http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/bootstrapping/advanced_cloud_driver_usage.html)):

```
installer {
    connectionTestRouteResolutionTimeoutMillis 120000
    connectionTestIntervalMillis 5000
    connectionTestConnectTimeoutMillis 10000

    fileTransferConnectionTimeoutMillis 10000
    fileTransferRetries 3
    fileTransferPort -1 
    fileTransferConnectionRetryIntervalMillis 5000

    remoteExecutionPort -1
    remoteExecutionConnectionTimeoutMillis 10000
}
```

However, trying to bootstrap the management vm, I receive the following error:

```
cloudify@default> bootstrap-cloud --verbose <openstack-icehouse-xxx>
Setting security profile to "nonsecure".
No such property: fileTransferPort for class: dslEntity :
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: fileTransferPort for class: dslEntity
```

Can someone explain me where the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: The cloud file is probably malformed and the parser can't read it. Attach the full file, or link to it.

Comment: Thank you  Barak. I have commented the fileTransfer* strings, solving the problem.

Comment: Can someone tell me what is the meaning of all the "connectionTest*" strings?

Comment: The installer process first performs a tcp connection test. When it passes, the file transfer move configuration files to the target machine, and then the remote execution step launches the agent